# Cannot merge branches after SVN to git migration

Tags: git, svn

We recently did a migration from SVN to GitHub. Due to the overall size of the SVN repo, we only migrated `trunk` (this became `master`) and our current `release` branch. `master` and `release` have been regularly merged prior to the migration.

Everything seemed okay, and we started doing some work in git. We are at about 2 days in and a discovery we have made is that this results in `master` and the `release` branch not being mergeable (`refusing to merge unrelated histories`).

I did try and do a merge with `--allow-unrelated-histories` as a quick test, but this results in a lot of conflict. We also have a lot of binaries. Our repo is unfortunately large.

I'm trying to get a hold of the team that did the migration to find out more about how they did this, but wanted to be proactive in better understanding what happened and possible ways to address this.

Was this a problem with how they did the migration? Meaning, post-migration, should the two branches still have had related history? Or is this not possible?

Is there any way in git to resolve this?

One way I can think of which is a nuclear option would be to folder diff and declare bankruptcy on the other branch.

Another option. I could see would be in SVN, merging `release` into `trunk`, then re-syncing `trunk` to our `master` and just re-doing our changes.

Any thoughts on how to address this would be most appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the original svn repository? Can you try performing the migration yourself (with a local repository)? I think that an import should correctly handle branches, (that is, should translate subversion branches into mergeable git branches) but honestly it's been close to 10 years since I last had to do a git-svn import.

Comment: Great suggestion. I hadn't thought of that. I did do the migration myself, but I found that I could not successfully do the migration with 2 branches. I also discovered from the team a possible reason for the problem. They have been merging dev branches into both master and release. Apparently they do not merge between master and release. So I suspect now the lack of related history may be from this.